# Request.QueryString giving me space instead of + sign

Tags: asp.net

If I have a URL value http://Localhost/default.aspx?ts=/+m2dAZZA3DaavaaupUXkZL83n7TwmCVm

Request.QueryString[ts] is giving me

/ m2dAZZA3DaavaaupUXkZL83n7TwmCVm

How to ensure that I get all the value from the Querystring

is there an encoding or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever code that generates your URL needs to escape it properly. Use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` server-side or `ecodeURIComponent()` client-side

Answer (score 2):

Use: http://Localhost/default.aspx?ts=/%2Bm2dAZZA3DaavaaupUXkZL83n7TwmCVm instead.

Special characters in URLs are formatted as %XX where XX is the hex representation of the ASCII value. In this case, the + sign is 43, thus our URL value will be %2B.

Answer (score 1):

try using Server.urlencode and Server.urldecode or use **%2B instead of +**

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) is list of encodings to use for such characters.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Server.UrlEncode()` or `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a `+` in the parameter value.  Instead, choose another character that is URL friendly and will not otherwise be used.  Replace the `+` before adding the value to the URL.  Then replace it with a `+` when the value is retrieved.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using special characters in URLs, they simply have to be encoded first.