# Query String Returning Different Values to that of the actual in the url

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, http

```
http://localhost:1079/BattleSimulator.aspx?userID=Unregistered_User&Troops=1111%1111%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0!1111%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0&Research=10%10%10%10%10%10%0!10%10%10%10%10%10%0&Sanctuary=0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0!0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0&Inventory=False%False%False%False%False%False!False%False%False%False%False%False&other=5!0&RNG=0&Dragons=-1%-1%-1%-1!-1%-1%-1%-1&BattleArts=0%0%0!0%0%0&Kaizer=2310000%1510000%0%15867000%910000%875!5011000%2810000%3158%182972948%2810000%803
```

^ this is the original Query Passed onto server,

But this is parsed on a very different way on the server

Ex:
http://prntscr.com/3h90fs

http://prntscr.com/3h90o2

the string returned from

```
Extention.QueryString("Troops")
```

is "111111%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0!1111%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0%0"

Why is this happening ? is it a bug ?

Comment: Don't post code as images, post it as text. So that it will be easy to copy/paste.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: that wasnt the code i was posting as images but the debug info from MS visual studio showing the difference in output.

Comment: are you using url encoding? if not then use it.

Comment: is % sign considered a special character or something that messes with things ? im using it as a seperator

Comment: btw: it's spelled: "Extension"

Comment: Congrats you know your spellings , heres a cookie !

Answer (score 2):

There are many chars that are reserved and can't be used in querystring. % is one of those.
You have to Encode a string to be shure that it will be properly decoded to the same string in the server.

In C# this can be done this way:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(destinationURL);
```

Comment: This works since % is a reserved character in urls (used to encode special characters)

Answer (score 1):

**Why is this happening ?**

> Because added any(some) spaces(White Character ) between your values.

**is it a bug ?**

> Nope. It's not a bug .

### **Solution.**

> You need use *`Trim()`* or remove Empty values by using *`Replace(" ","")`* in your query string values before send query string

See this links

[Get Query String value containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894680/get-query-string-value-containing-spaces)

[Passing in a querystring with a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507548/passing-in-a-querystring-with-a-space)

http://blogfornet.com/tag/how-to-use-space-in-url-query-string/

[Request.QueryString giving me space instead of + sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790070/request-querystring-giving-me-space-instead-of-sign)

Comment: No empty spaces in the request

Comment: Please see my answer one more time, i have added some links for that. I hope this helps to you!

Comment: Hey thanx man though this isnt the exact ans , the prob was with me using % symbol as a seperator in the request , it somehow messes with their encoding of some other characters , so i replaced % with another character "z" and tweeked the functions accordingly.

+1 for links and attempt at help :D

Comment: -1 This is plain wrong. The issue is that % is a reserved character and has nothing to do with whitespaces.